# Sync local and internet db

Tags: mysql, synchronization

I have a PHP (CI + Fuel) app online for managing a few stores. The problem is that sometimes the stores lost the internet connection.

The system must be operational at all times so I need to have a copy of the db in a local server.

The question is, what is the easy way to sync the data between online server and local server?

My idea, when the internet server go off is work normaly in the local db and alson save all the insert and update querys in a table. Then when internet come back, run all the querys to sync.